# What is the good starting point for Clojure development on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure

What is the good starting point for Clojure development on Google AppEngine?

Seems like there are two competing libraries appengine-magic and compojure-gae.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic

A nice lib. It takes away most of the stuff you don't want to deal with. It just as easy as a normal Clojure Webapplication.

For more information about Clojure Webapplications.

- http://cleancode.se/2010/08/30/getting-started-with-compojure.html
- http://cleancode.se/2010/09/03/getting-started-with-compojure2.html
- http://github.com/abedra/clojure-web
- http://formpluslogic.blogspot.com/
- http://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar

Blogs about Clojure and GAE (some stuff is outdated):

- http://compojureongae.posterous.com/
- http://www.hackers-with-attitude.com/
- http://carpathia.blogspot.com/2010/05/yet-another-clojure-compojure-google.html

The appengine-magic lib is really what you should look at. Im working with it too.

Comment: +1 to compilation of good refs. I think compojureongae is a good choice if you want to build a example from zero and to know a little bit the magic under the hood (it's relativily recent), although appengine-magic is good too. The problem i found with hacker-with-attitude is they are on old version of compojure without ring and the deps of its datastore library are a little bit out-of-date.

Answer (score 3):

Start with this presentation:

http://www.slideshare.net/smartrevolution/how-a-clojure-pet-project-turned-into-a-fullblown-cloudcomputing-webapp

Then continue here:
http://www.hackers-with-attitude.com/2010/04/clojure-google-app-engine-setup-update.html